Are there instances of the "Lights Out" puzzle that can be solved faster with the square-root-of-NOT?
The "Lights Out" puzzle is a simple solitaire game played on an $m\times n$ grid of light bulbs and corresponding switches. Conventionally by flipping a switch at row $i$, column $j$, that bulb and the (von Neumann) neighboring bulbs are negated. When presented with such a grid with some bulbs on and the remaining bulbs off, the goal is to flip a sequence of switches to get all of the lights turned off.
From Wikipedia:

Each switch effectively performs a "NOT" operation on all corresponding bulbs.  Brief reflection shows that the puzzle is commutative and in order to solve it, all that matters is the specific switches to be toggled (and not, the order in which the toggles are performed).
Nonetheless, are there any instances of the game where we could get a reduction in the number of switches that need to be toggled, by using square-root-of-NOT gates in lieu of (or in addition to) the NOT gates used in the conventional puzzle?  For example, instance on a cylinder (or torus or Klein bottle)?
My real motivation is to whether this would count as a demonstration of quantum computational advantage, because the $\sqrt{\text{NOT}}$ is a common quantum gate that can create superposition.  Here there are no two-bit/two qubit gates (much less any entangling two-qubit gates) to worry about, so such an implementation may be simpler.

Judging by the question here over at the Quantum Computing SE, the quantum algorithm for the Light's Out game has been considered by others previously. (The Medium post found here might be relevant but is gated to Medium accounts.)

@Semiclassical thanks! I had seen that question before; it suggests using Grover's algorithm to actively solve the puzzle in ~$O(n)$ steps (where classically you'd need $O(n^2)$ steps for an $n\times n$-board.) My question is slightly different, insofar as Grover's algorithm may be overkill as compared to just using $\sqrt{\text{NOT}}$ gates (because Grover needs some two-qubit gates).

CW from self-answer

A $4\times 1$ (or $8\times 1$ or $10\times 1$...) puzzle that wraps around as a cylinder has an advantage when the two cells neighboring the target cell only see a $\sqrt{\text{NOT}}$ operation (and the target is fully negated each click).
Classically when all $4$ (or $8$ or $10$) bulbs are lit up, the only solution is to toggle each of the switches.  But by applying the square-root-of-NOT gates only on the neighboring bulbs, only every other switch needs to be toggled.
I don't know if there's a grid that's impossible classically but that's solvable when some neighboring cells act as square-root-of-NOT gates.
